# Are there any chances of losing data during Boot repair

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, ubuntu-14.04, bootrepair

I had dual booted Ubuntu 14.04 along with Windows 8.1 but for some reasons I decided to uninstall Ubuntu. So I deleted the partition containing Ubuntu and now want to perform a Windows boot repair. I am thinking of doing this using a bootable USB flash drive.

The question that I want to ask is - Is any risk of losing data on my hard drive during this boot repair?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not have any issues.  Windows boot repair will look at the hard drives and see there a NTFS partition with Windows on it.  It should make it bootable again with no issues and without losing any data.

However, it is *always* a good idea to make a backup.